# remove everything before a character in a column

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a table like this

```
start end chr
  1   10  H300Chr01
  10  50  H500Chr02
```

I would like to replace everything before "Chr" in column3.

My desired output would be

```
start end chr
  1   10  Chr01
  10  50  Chr02
```

I know that `sed` can do things like this:

```
sed 's/^.*Chr/Chr/' table.txt
```

Could you please tell me how I could achieve this for a specific column or a couple of columns?

Comment: > _".... or couple of columns?"_- can you show an example of that case too? leading whitespaces matters? or even number of whitespaces in between fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a specific column:

```
awk '{sub(/.*Chr/,"Chr",$3); print}' file
```

The first argument of `sub` is the pattern to match, the second is the replacement and last is the target. The outcome is stored to the target.
See also [awk string functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html).

And this is expandable for more columns, example:

```
awk '{sub(/.*Chr1/,"Chr1",$1); sub(/.*Chr2/,"Chr2",$2); print}' file
```

Note that matching is *greedy* as expected, which is the desired behaviour for your data.

To format the output, it's probably more convenient than defining `OFS` to pipe the output to `column -t`, for a tab-like pretty-printing with actual spaces, no tabs.

Comment: This answer does not give the exact output required by the original question.
This answer mangles the output by compressing multiple spaces and removing leading spaces, and then suggests using other programs to try to restore formatting similar to (but not identical to) the actual output required.  The answer by `terdon` is better.

Comment: You can use GNU awk [printf](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Printf-Examples.html) function and achieve any output you 'd like. Also, please have in mind that keeping the content separated from formatting is a basic principle.

Answer (score 6):

With some (all?) `awk` implementations, certainly the GNU `awk` and the `mawk` I have on my Arch Linux system, you can set the field separator to a regular expression which makes awk keep the original separator of the file. To illustrate:

```
$ awk '{$1=$1;print}' file
start end chr
1 10 H300Chr01
10 50 H500Chr02

$ awk -F'[ ]' '{$1=$1;print}' file
start end chr
  1   10  H300Chr01
  10  50  H500Chr02
```

With this in mind, we can make the change to the last (I say last and not third because this approach redraws the line and the numbering changes depending on the number of spaces) field without altering the spacing with something like this:

```
$ awk -F'[ ]' '{sub(/.*Chr/,"Chr",$NF);}1' file
start end chr
  1   10  Chr01
  10  50  Chr02
```

Alternatively, you can do it with `perl`:

```
$ perl -pne 's/(\s*\S+\s+\S+\s+)\S+(Chr)/$1$2/;' file 
start end chr
  1   10  Chr01
  10  50  Chr02
```

Or, to ensure you only match the first occurrence of `Chr` in the third field, in case there are more than one:

```
perl -pe 's/(\s*\S+\s+\S+\s+)\S+?(Chr)/$1$2/;' file
```

Comment: +1, but why both `-p` and `-n` ? I think that `-p` should suffice

Comment: Thanks, @DanieleGrassini, the `-n` was left over from when I was trying some different approaches using `-lane`.

Comment: Using `awk -F'[ ]'` just for formatting, is changing the number of input fields. So you will have trouble when scaling this oneliner for more columns or for an inner 
column. `column -t` should be prefered or defining `OFS` instead of changing the input content, to keep formatting separated from content.

Comment: @thanasisp yes, that's why I point out in the answer that it changes the number of fields and why I used `$NF` and why I provided a perl solution as well. Neither defining `OFS` nor `column -t` would work, unfortunately, since we have leading spaces

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you:

```
< file awk '{p=index($3,"Chr"); $3=substr($3,p); print}' | column -t
```

This looks for the substring "Chr" in the third field, and sets the third field to the remainder starting with Chr. (If "Chr" is not found, the whole field remains.)

Unfortunately, awk merges whitespace when you change part of the line. `column -t` lines up the columns again.

That results in

```
start  end  chr
1      10   Chr01
10     50   Chr02
```

(Notice the columns have changed alignment.)

If that's not good enough, we can adapt this [answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20836890/2132213) by Håkon Hægland:

```
awk '{n=split($0,fields," ",seps); p=index(fields[3],"Chr"); fields[3]=substr(fields[3],p); line=seps[0]; for (i=1; i <=n; i++) { line=(line fields[i] seps[i]); } print line; }' file
```

which is probably worth putting in its own awk script, instead of running on the command line.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
{
    n = split($0, fields, " ", seps)
    p = index(fields[3], "Chr")
    fields[3] = substr(fields[3], p)
    line = seps[0]
    for (i=1; i <=n; i++) 
        line=(line fields[i] seps[i])
    print line
}
```

If that's saved in say `coledit.awk` and made executable, then running `./coledit.awk file` results in your desired output (with original whitespace unchanged).

Comment: why use `< file` when awk already has the ability to open file?

Comment: @phuclv some people like seeing the name of the file first on the command line so this is better than `cat file | awk...` for those people and it allows the shell to open the file instead of the command so you get consistent file-opening-failure error messages if you use that idiom for all commands (including those like `tr` that can't open a file themselves) and on a file opening failure  `< file awk '...' > output` won't create `output`  create an empty (or overwrite if it exists) file named `output` . The downside is you can't do that for opening multiple files and you lose FILENAME access.

Answer (score 3):

Using **Perl**

```bsh
perl -pe 's/\G\S*?(?=Chr)//
  if m/(?:\S+\s+){2}/cg;
' file
```

---

**POSIX sed**

```bsh
sed '
  s/[^[:space:]]\{1,\}/\
&/3
  s/\n[^[:space:]]*Chr/Chr/
  s/\n//
' file
```

---

Since sed doesn't support non greedy regexes we will implement it using it's constructs in GNU sed in extended regex mode.

```bsh
sed -E '
  s/\S+/\n&\n/3
  /\n.*Chr.*\n/ta
  s/\n//g;b
  :a
  s/(\n.*)(Chr.*)\n/\1\n\2/
  ta
  s/\n.*\n//
' file
```

---

**awk** while preserving formatting.

```bsh
s="[[:space:]]" S="[^[:space:]]"

re="^$s*($S+$s+){2}" \
awk -v ss="Chr" '
BEGIN { re = ENVIRON["re"] }
match($0,re) && (p=index($3,ss)) {
  l = RLENGTH
  $0 = substr($0,1,l) \
       substr($0,p+l) ;
}1' file
```

---

Answer (score 0):

In `sed` the `\s` is for white-space characters and `\S` is for non-white-space.
Then the `*` is just any number of repetition.

```
sed 's/\S*Chr/Chr/'
```

Comment: This isn't targeting the third column, it will replace the first occurrence of non-space followed by `Chr` no matter where it is. Also, the `\s` and `\S` aren't part of the `sed` specification, while many `sed` implementations do support them, you can't be sure that all will.

Comment: @terdon It seem really unlikely that the first and the second columns have a non-numeric data inside, since they are named start and end, and have only numeric values in the sample showed.

Comment: @niklassc `\S` is not standard (as said by @terdon  ). If you replace `\S` with `[^[:space:]]` your `sed` will be portable to other `sed`, while still catch both spaces and tabs.

Comment: @DanieleGrassini yes, it is unlikely. But the question specified "third column" so I felt it was worth pointing out. Also, the standard format for this sort of data, called [a BED file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BED_(file_format)), does have the chromosome as the first field, so it's not inconceivable the OP or the next user to find the question will try to use the solution somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
raku -ne 'given .words() { put .[0..1] ~ " " ~ .[2].subst: /^ <(.*?)> Chr .* $/ };'
```

OR

```perl
raku -ne 'put .[0..1] ~ " " ~ .[2].subst: /^ <(.*?)> Chr .* $/ given .words;'
```

Above are answers coded in Raku, a member of the Perl family of programming languages. Briefly, data is read in with the `-ne` linewise non-autoprinting flags. Input is broken on whitespace using `.words`, and the resulting array of elements is addressed using the `.[0..1]` or `.[2]` postfix index brackets. The `.[0..1]` (first and second columns) are out-`put` directly, while the third column is `.subst` substituted such that any characters seen before the first occurrence of `Chr` are deleted.

Regarding the regex above: the `<(…)>` match delimiters ensure that while the entire column is matched between `/^ … $/`, the elements outside of `<(…)>` are dropped from the final match object. [ Then, using `subst` without a replacement instructs Raku to delete the match object, in this case, the `<(.*?)>` non-greedy regex match before `Chr`].

Sample Input:

```
start end chr
  1   10  H300Chr01
  10  50  H500Chr02
```

Sample Output:

```
start end chr
1 10 Chr01
10 50 Chr02
```

The code above seems pretty mechanical, and you can get prettier results (i.e. nicely aligned columns) by piping your output through `column -t`, as suggested by @NickMatteo. Alternatively a more powerful approach might be to first convert your file to CSV via Raku's `Text::CSV` module. See link below.

https://github.com/Tux/CSV/blob/master/doc/Text-CSV.pdf (click the Download link)
https://raku.org